# jquery display a list of items in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I want to display a list of item inside

sample html code

```
<h3 id="game-filter" class="gamesection">
           <span>Game</span></h3>
        <div id="game-filter-div" style="padding: 0;">
            <ul id="gamelist">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

code

```
var games = new Array();
    games[0] = "World of Warcraft";
    games[1] = "Lord of the Rings Online";
    games[2] = "Aion";
    games[3] = "Eve Online";
    games[4] = "Final Fantasy XI";
    games[5] = "City of Heros";
    games[6] = "Champions Online";
    games[7] = "Dark Age of Camelot";
    games[8] = "Warhammer Online";
    games[9] = "Age of Conan";
    function pageLoaded(){
        var list = "";

            for(i=0; i<games.length; i++){
        list ="<li>"+games[i]+"</li>";
        $("#gamelist").append(list);
        //document.getElementById("gamelist").innerHTML=list;
        list = "";
        }

}
```

Seems there is wrong with my js code. It doesn't output anything

Comment: it is not javascript, its jQuery. did you reference the jQuery api?

Comment: also, you are not calling pageLoaded() function anywhere

Comment: Are you running `items in the array` in your code or is it commented out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are so many things you are doing wrong in it.

Firstly, it is not pure javascript, its jquery.

you need to reference [jQuery api](http://jquery.com/download/) to be able to use jQuery.

however, you can achieve what you want through pure javascript also.

Now let's look at your mistakes

1. you have created a function `pageLoaded`, but have not called it anywhere. You need to call a function in order to make its logic work. Am assuming you want to call your `pageLoaded` method when the page is ready. you can either call it on body load or simply inside jQuery's [.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29) i.e  `$(document).ready(function(){ pageLoaded()});`. 
   This method simply ensures, your logic executes when the dom is ready
2. you have written non-keyword, meaningless words inside your method "items in the array". remove it in order to make your function work. Am assuming you wanted to put a comment over there, put a comment like this inside script tag:

   ```
    //items in the array
   ```
3. you are not concatenating new values to your `list` variable, you are overwritting its content with each iteration, so instead of `list ="<li>"+games[i]+"</li>";` this, do this

   ```
    list +="<li>"+games[i]+"</li>";
   ```
4. finally, you are appending the `list` to `#gamelist` inside the for loop. do it outside the loop. once your list is complete. and remove the line `list=" "`
   so place this line  `$("#gamelist").append(list);` outside the for loop.

try your function like this:

```
var games = new Array();
    games[0] = "World of Warcraft";
    games[1] = "Lord of the Rings Online";
    games[2] = "Aion";
    games[3] = "Eve Online";
    games[4] = "Final Fantasy XI";
    games[5] = "City of Heros";
    games[6] = "Champions Online";
    games[7] = "Dark Age of Camelot";
    games[8] = "Warhammer Online";
    games[9] = "Age of Conan";
$(document).ready(function(){
        var list = "";
        for(i=0; i<games.length; i++){
        list +="<li>"+games[i]+"</li>";
        }
    $("#gamelist").append(list);

});
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkD6F/)

Answer (score 5):

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/F9ACq/)

```
<h3 id="game-filter" class="gamesection"><span>Game</span></h3>

<div id="game-filter-div" style="padding: 0;">
    <ul id="gamelist"></ul>
</div>

var games = ["World of Warcraft", "Lord of the Rings Online", "Aion", "Eve Online", "Final Fantasy XI", "City of Heros", "Champions Online", "Dark Age of Camelot", "Warhammer Online", "Age of Conan"];

var gamelist = document.getElementById("gamelist");

games.forEach(function (game) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");

    li.textContent = game;
    gamelist.appendChild(li);
});
```

This is pure Javascript but I see you changed your tag to jQuery, but I will leave it here.

Additionally if you didn't want to create the array initialised, like I did above, you could have done it like this, as `new Array()` is considered bad practise.

```
var games = new Array();

games.push("World of Warcraft");
games.push("Lord of the Rings Online");
games.push("Aion");
games.push("Eve Online");
games.push("Final Fantasy XI");
games.push("City of Heros");
games.push("Champions Online");
games.push("Dark Age of Camelot");
games.push("Warhammer Online");
games.push("Age of Conan");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the listview after dynamically appending elements in it; otherwise it won't update.

```
 $("#gamelist").append(list).listview("refresh");
```